# How to implement conditional encapsulation in C#

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, encapsulation

I was wondering how one can conditionally hide data in  class.
For instance , lets say I have a class called Car which has three fields :
Engine , MeterReading and Mileage.

I have three other entities called : Driver , Mechanic and Passenger.
 Now what I want is that :

A Driver  should only be able to access Mileage ( and not Engine and MeterReading)

A Mechanic should only be able to access Engine and Mileage( and not MeterReading)

A Passenger should only be able to access MeterReading ( and not Engine and Mileage )

What could be the best way to implement this ..( without basing the whole logic on  if else statements ) ?

Any ideas guys ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28VS.71%29.aspx). It hides implementation of interface when object is accessed by its type. The implementation is accessible only when accessing by interface. In your example:

```
interface IUsableByPassenger
{
    MeterReading MeterReading
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

interface IUsableByDriver
{
    Mileage Mileage
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

interface IUsableByMechanic : IUsableByDriver
{
    Engine Engine
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

class Car : IUsableByMechanic, IUsableByPassenger
{
    Mileage IUsableByDriver.Mileage
    {
        // implement mileage access
    }

    Engine IUsableByMechanic.Engine
    {
        // implement engine access
    }

    MeterReading IUsableByPassenger.MeterReading
    {
        // implement engine access
    }
}

class Mechanic
{
    public Mechanic(IUsableByMechanic usable)
    {
        // usable.MeterReading is not here
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it should be pointed out that this only guards against accidents while coding, but it is not a security measure against hostile clients because the client code can still cast an instance of `IUsableByPassenger` to `Car` and then to `IUsableByMechanic` and all the others.

Comment: Sure, but there is no way to avoid that when exposing any object capable somehow of doing more than exposed. One can always use reflection to find a type, read privates etc.

Comment: @A: It is possible to prevent untrusted client code from using reflection, but not to prevent simple casting.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for all your answers .. the "explicit interface implementation" is what I was looking for .

Comment: And apologies for any confusion (accidental down-voting) that I might have caused ..( I'm kinda new to this :) )

Answer (score 13):

The first idea that came to mind would be to have your `Car` class implement 3 different interfaces which each other class can use to interact with your `Car` class.

For example, (and my names can definitely be improved upon, but you should get the idea), the `IDriverAccess` interface could be as follows:

```
public interface IDriverAccess
{
  double Mileage { get; }
}
```

The `IMechanicAccess` interface could be as follows:

```
public interface IMechanicAccess
{
  EngineObject Engine { get; set; }

  double Mileage { get; }
}
```

And so on. Your car class can then implement these interfaces, but the classes for the driver, mechanic, & passenger will just use the interfaces to interact with the object.

```
public Car : IDriverAccess, IMechanicAccess, IPassengerAccess
{
  // implement the interfaces
}
```

Comment: Of course it should be pointed out that this only guards against accidents while coding, but it is not a security measure against hostile clients because the client code can still cast an instance of `IDriverAccess` to `Car` and access everything.

Comment: But when you implement that interfaces implicitly, `Car` class outside `Mechanic` or `Driver` (i.e. when accessed by nasty `Thief`) will still expose everything.

Comment: @Timewi and @A, if this a real concern, you can make the Car an internal class and only ever expose it as various interfaces.  Of course, the Thief could still force-cast between interfaces or even use Reflection to break in.  You can prevent force-casting by implementing the different interfaces with sub-classes (this can be a good use case for private nested classes), but there's not much you can do about Reflection besides running with partial trust.

Answer (score 2):

I would create these interfaces:

```
    public interface IDriviableCar
{
    object Mileage { get; }
}

public interface IRepairableCar
{
    object Engine { get; }
}

public interface IHirableCar
{
    object MeterReader { get; }
}

public class Car : IDriviableCar, IRepairableCar, IHirableCar
{
    private object _mileage;

    private object _engine;

    private object _meterReader;

    public object Mileage
    {
        get { return _mileage; }
    }

    public object Engine
    {
        get { return _engine; }
    }

    public object MeterReader
    {
        get { return _meterReader; }
    }
}
```

And let each person use the interface to access the car.

Comment: As above - when you implement that interfaces implicitly, `Car` class outside `Mechanic` or `Driver` (i.e. when accessed by nasty `Thief`) will still expose everything.

Comment: But they should not have access to it and that is the key.

Comment: Of course it should be pointed out that this only guards against accidents while coding, but it is not a security measure against hostile clients because the client code can still cast an instance of `IDrivableCar` to `Car` and access everything.

Answer (score 2):

make class Car implemented interfaces IEngine,ImaterReading  and so.
Give each entity only specifyc interface access.
say a drive got IMilage access only, a mechanic IMilage and IEngine.

Comment: Sorry .. that was accidental !